# Create two descending bubble plots and connect them based on values found in same data set

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I have the following data in which I want to create a side by side comparison using a bubble plot(larger values have larger bubbles) in descending order between Animal and Food with lines that connect them respectively.

Data Table Form:

```
Animal  Food
Cat Hard_Food
Cat Hard_Food
Cat Hard_Food
Cat Hard_Food
Cat Soft_Food
Cat Soft_Food
Cat Soft_Food
Cat Mouse
Cat Soft_Food
Cat Soft_Food
Dog Hard_Food
Dog Hard_Food
Dog Hard_Food
Dog Hard_Food
Dog Soft_Food
Dog Soft_Food
Dog Soft_Food
Dog Soft_Food
Dog Meat
Snake   Mouse
Snake   Meat
Snake   Meat
Snake   Meat
```

Summarized Table form:

```
    Hard_Food   Meat    Soft_Food   Mouse   Grand Total
Cat        4       0       5           1    10
Dog        4       1       4           0    9
Snake      0       3       0           1    4
GrandTotal 8       4       9           2    23
```

Python DataFrame:

```
ani_foo = {'Animal': ['Cat','Cat','Cat','Cat','Cat','Cat','Cat','Cat','Cat','Cat','Dog','Dog','Dog','Dog','Dog','Dog','Dog','Dog','Dog','Snake','Snake','Snake','Snake'],
        'Food': ['Hard_Food','Hard_Food','Hard_Food','Hard_Food','Soft_Food','Soft_Food','Soft_Food','Mouse','Soft_Food','Soft_Food','Hard_Food','Hard_Food','Hard_Food','Hard_Food','Soft_Food','Soft_Food','Soft_Food','Soft_Food','Meat','Mouse','Meat','Meat','Meat']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(ani_foo, columns = ['Animal', 'Food'])
```

Desired output(manually created via Excel):

[image]

Comment: Looks like a very manual but straightforwards process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using networkx library creating at bipartite networks:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ani_foo = {'Animal': ['Cat','Cat','Cat','Cat','Cat','Cat','Cat','Cat','Cat','Cat','Dog','Dog','Dog','Dog','Dog','Dog','Dog','Dog','Dog','Snake','Snake','Snake','Snake'],
        'Food': ['Hard_Food','Hard_Food','Hard_Food','Hard_Food','Soft_Food','Soft_Food','Soft_Food','Mouse','Soft_Food','Soft_Food','Hard_Food','Hard_Food','Hard_Food','Hard_Food','Soft_Food','Soft_Food','Soft_Food','Soft_Food','Meat','Mouse','Meat','Meat','Meat']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(ani_foo, columns = ['Animal', 'Food'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Animal', 'Food')
G.add_nodes_from(df['Animal'], bipartite=0)
G.add_nodes_from(df['Food'], bipartite=1)
s = df.stack().value_counts()
s1 = s.index +'\n'+ s.astype(str)
pos = {node:[0, i] for i, node in enumerate(df['Animal'])}
pos.update({node:[1,i] for i, node in enumerate(df['Food'])})
color_dict = {'Cat':'g', 'Dog':'b', 'Snake':'y'}
ec = [color_dict[c] for i in G.edges for c in i if c in color_dict.keys()]
nx.draw_networkx(G, 
                 node_size=[s[i]*250 for i in G.nodes], 
                 pos=pos, 
                 labels = s1.to_dict(), 
                 node_color='lightblue',
                 edge_color=ec)
plt.axis('off')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Is there a way to adjust the image within the plot to avoid labels being cutoff?  I tried various options found on Stackoverlfow but I couldn't get one to work and thought you might have a different approach. For example, if you change the first "cat" in "ani_foo" to "Catttttttttttttttttttttt", the "C" is no longer visible in the chart.